# Unintended chorus like effect when recording Fender P bass through Behringer Xenyx Q502USB

Tags: recording, bass-guitar, audio

I'm relatively new to the home studio game. I have started recording demos using my Behringer Xenyx Q502USB as an audio interface.

It mostly works fine - but when I record bass through it the sound is, well, terrible. My bass is a Fender P-Bass, I am running it through a Behringer Ultra DI DI-20 (attenuation set to 0db), and into the audio interface.

The thing that is particularly frustrating is that it makes a chorus like effect when playing the low notes. This makes it really difficult to record good bass parts. It also makes this sound when I adjust the attenuation on the DI box, and then when I go directly into the audio interface.

Has anyone here got any advice / had a similar issue before? How do I fix it!

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure we understand the signal chain, you have a 1/4” cable from the bass to the DI and then an XLR cable from the DI to the interface? Do you also have a bass amp around? I’m wondering if you don’t hear the sound when you play through an amp. Also, do you have a recording of the sound you could put on SoundCloud or something and add a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hearing the chorusing while you are recording or when you playback?

If it is only during recording, then you have a monitoring problem - most likely cause by hearing the live signal together with the recorded signal (which will be later).